# Add spacing beneath multi-line covington gloss

Tags: vertical-alignment, linguistics, covington

I would like there to be some space below the last (populated) line of a `covington` gloss so that long glosses are easier to read.

This code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{covington}

\begin{document}

\digloss
{\'Island er eyja. Evr\'opa er \'alfa og \'Island er hluti af Evr\'opu. Reykjav\'ik er borg. Gullfoss er foss.}
{Iceland is {an island}. Europe is {a continent} and Iceland is part of Europe. Reykjavík is {a city}. Gullfoss is {a waterfall}.}
{}

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

Instead, I would like something like this:

[image]

I tried using `setspace` but `covington` seems to ignore spacing configured by other packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting first with a workaround, one could output a deep strut (here `\gap`), at least once per line of gloss.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{covington}
\newcommand\gap{\rule[-20pt]{0pt}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
\digloss
{\'Island er eyja. Evr\'opa er \'alfa og \'Island er hluti af Evr\'opu. Reykjav\'ik er borg. Gullfoss er foss.}
{\gap Iceland is {an island}. Europe is {a continent} and Iceland is part of Europe. Reykjavík is {a city}. Gullfoss is {a waterfall}.}
{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this workaround can be automated, by including it as an option at invocation: `[fsii=\gap]`.  The `fsii` option (p.10 of documentation) is supposed to be a "font setting" for the 2nd line of the gloss.

[image]

But here, I include the deep strut as the font setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{covington}
\newcommand\gap{\rule[-20pt]{0pt}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
\digloss[fsii=\gap]
{\'Island er eyja. Evr\'opa er \'alfa og \'Island er hluti af Evr\'opu. 
  Reykjav\'ik er borg. Gullfoss er foss. \'Island er eyja. Evr\'opa er \'alfa 
  og \'Island er hluti af Evr\'opu. Reykjav\'ik er borg. Gullfoss er foss.}
{Iceland is {an island}. Europe is {a continent} and Iceland is part of Europe. 
  Reykjavík is {a city}. Gullfoss is {a waterfall}. Iceland is {an island}. 
  Europe is {a continent} and Iceland is part of Europe. Reykjavík is {a city}. 
  Gullfoss is {a waterfall}.}
{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

FYI the next version of `covington` (2.11) will include support for customization of spacing between gloss lines via dedicated environment options (`addlinesepi`, `addlinesepii`, and `addlinesepiii`). As other options, these can be set locally and globally.